# nested Json string into array in vb.net or uipath

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, uipath, jsonserializer

I have json string that has the combination of nested level and normal as per below string. I wanted to extract values as below. Values needed to extracted from **"FrameVariables"**

arrary1: two dimensional array (combination of location, Gender, Nationality)

{

(Riyadh,Male,Saudi National)(Target of Saudi National),

(Riyadh,Male,Expat Arab)(Target of Expat Arab),

(Riyadh,Female,Saudi National)(Target of Saudi National)

(Riyadh,female,Expat Arab)(Target of Expat Arab),

(Jeddah,Male,Saudi National)(Target of Saudi National),

.

.

.

(Damam,Male,Saudi National)(Target of Saudi National),

..

(Damam,female,Expat Arab)(Target of Expat Arab)

}

Array2: Two dimensional array (Age)
{
(18 - 25 Years),(Target of 18 - 25 Years),
(26 - 35 Years),(Target of 26 - 35 Years),
(36 - 50 Years),(Target of 36 - 50 Years)
}

Points to taken care: This json is dynamic, the values and names will change based on the data.

[image]

Sample Json String:

```
{
"Target": null,
    "FrameVariables": [
    {
        "Id": "c61313a1-a7a2-4859-3c41-a8d20cda45cd",
        "DefinitionId": "81da60bf-7a65-4324-4074-e2b049a76314",
        "Name": "Location",
        "IsHidden": false,
        "Levels": [
            {
                "Id": "03b7dde4-352e-46f5-bcff-ee998cd88cca",
                "DefinitionId": "51e54413-1a11-4520-729f-de3ba61b78cb",
                "Name": "Riyadh",
                "Variables": [
                    {
                        "Id": "cc2e0f8e-b0da-44eb-ed6b-ef5a6aac43eb",
                        "DefinitionId": "b1f620bc-896c-4d5d-fdf2-db72a4c54331",
                        "Name": "Gender",
                        "IsHidden": false,
                        "Levels": [
                            {
                                "Id": "15b6c79a-b7ac-41e3-9231-e8776fa88c29",
                                "DefinitionId": "d5d23eaa-1322-4ee6-11c8-e0782a0e4dcc",
                                "Name": "Male",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {
                                        "Id": "d8392973-4659-4ede-933f-4a890579daad",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "7633925b-ede2-43fe-43da-6ee0807b673a",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "1fa70d37-ca29-44f4-3653-b37a802092ce",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            },
                            {
                                "Id": "5ee34883-5a47-4582-fb40-d116faab70dc",
                                "DefinitionId": "7f839f5c-a333-47a3-5639-300ef13ab6f9",
                                "Name": "Female",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {

                                        "Id": "5ae5cd36-84c1-4149-bb31-10d2431d3faa",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "f4276438-0e02-459a-1c65-3d0d5414770f",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "318e5bd6-f11f-49ea-42eb-7f560b258031",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "Target": 20,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "60ae59c7-e9ce-45b2-8237-1e0fcb544208",
                "DefinitionId": "174e69fb-5ac3-451f-77ea-295c664c5c8b",
                "Name": "Jeddah",
                "Variables": [
                    {
                        "Id": "3516a9f9-4681-461d-5be9-2ec1523b87f4",
                        "DefinitionId": "b1f620bc-896c-4d5d-fdf2-db72a4c54331",
                        "Name": "Gender",
                        "IsHidden": false,
                        "Levels": [
                            {
                                "Id": "d528d8e0-cfe5-44e0-40ce-11e3ada35efd",
                                "DefinitionId": "d5d23eaa-1322-4ee6-11c8-e0782a0e4dcc",
                                "Name": "Male",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {
                                        "Id": "1cc29805-76e1-4e0c-eec4-77cec12f3df1",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "da9e125d-91af-4395-a60a-a0c0d58505cc",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "71dcb096-bb1b-454d-84cb-3447c1c0d2c5",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            },
                            {
                                "Id": "54de08f5-1bf0-4769-5c47-dd90a9c39aeb",
                                "DefinitionId": "7f839f5c-a333-47a3-5639-300ef13ab6f9",
                                "Name": "Female",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {
                                        "Id": "5ae3f935-484a-4713-64a9-91c817883ab3",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "5e10d95d-6475-4d8d-3b6c-cea26ca1f8dd",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "6234e632-d175-463b-1d0d-8abfb532a3ee",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "Target": 20,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "e4ade78b-600d-45eb-4768-6821690764ba",
                "DefinitionId": "601b4700-67a4-48e9-1f41-dc14c1a25870",
                "Name": "Dammam",
                "Variables": [
                    {
                        "Id": "912ddace-6bbf-4497-dba5-9d15b9c579a5",
                        "DefinitionId": "b1f620bc-896c-4d5d-fdf2-db72a4c54331",
                        "Name": "Gender",
                        "IsHidden": false,
                        "Levels": [
                            {
                                "Id": "0833cee6-d326-4204-fb50-1380233de763",
                                "DefinitionId": "d5d23eaa-1322-4ee6-11c8-e0782a0e4dcc",
                                "Name": "Male",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {
                                        "Id": "4b0563e7-44f8-4a3f-197a-cc35bf4b7662",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "39b2380e-554c-45a8-bc46-c9321228dc07",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "8c011c83-771c-4e82-d988-bb27693a4fe6",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            },
                            {
                                "Id": "b8289a68-493f-47a4-ffa8-4c8b699f6eb5",
                                "DefinitionId": "7f839f5c-a333-47a3-5639-300ef13ab6f9",
                                "Name": "Female",
                                "Variables": [
                                    {
                                        "Id": "794a49e5-3e87-444b-26ff-38bd66fb23c7",
                                        "DefinitionId": "c3eef7ce-8965-4dc3-cae5-88f2d42d7e23",
                                        "Name": "Nationality",
                                        "IsHidden": false,
                                        "Levels": [
                                            {
                                                "Id": "dd74c037-26d6-4e8f-b664-4cf2965a786e",
                                                "DefinitionId": "fafab836-8a9e-4aa3-19fb-22d4ecc6ea67",
                                                "Name": "Saudi National",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "Id": "4ab604f9-6004-4692-c45f-95b0a42dba74",
                                                "DefinitionId": "29ae0520-2029-41ff-2aa8-b4dbfae7253e",
                                                "Name": "Expat Arab",
                                                "Variables": [],
                                                "Target": 5,
                                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                                "IsHidden": false
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Target": 10,
                                "MaxTarget": null,
                                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                                "IsHidden": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "Target": 20,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "f1386e34-fbc1-4a98-b6a4-9659cd7de438",
        "DefinitionId": "a161af5c-ab90-4822-e7e9-103b186b7d20",
        "Name": "AGE",
        "IsHidden": false,
        "Levels": [
            {
                "Id": "0226d05f-80de-4009-abfa-76ac31e5bea5",
                "DefinitionId": "3fecf2cc-0618-47d7-b3ce-c4b272bf147d",
                "Name": "18 - 25 Years",
                "Variables": [],
                "Target": 6,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "479de48b-e78f-4143-8b69-2fdb60e32d08",
                "DefinitionId": "a4df428f-3cc1-4b2c-fde9-6e1dabe7714e",
                "Name": "26 - 35 Years",
                "Variables": [],
                "Target": 24,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "52ba8f15-1bc6-4672-8dd2-47735ec46d0a",
                "DefinitionId": "2fa0c2f7-cf49-45ca-7015-90b0f5f1dc03",
                "Name": "36 - 50 Years",
                "Variables": [],
                "Target": 30,
                "MaxTarget": null,
                "MaxOvershoot": null,
                "IsHidden": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**Deserialize Json**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/deserialize-json). This can deserialize JSON objects and JSON arrays. For content within the Object just apply that activity multiple times.